# Segfault when trying to add to end of linked list in C

Tags: c, list, insert, linked-list, valgrind

I'm trying to add a node to the end of my linked list, but it triggers a segfault, and further inspection from valgrind shows an infinite "Signal 11 dropped from thread 0" loop.

My .h file:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

struct fruit {
    char name[20];
};

struct node {
    struct fruit * data;
    struct node * next;
};

struct list {
    struct node * header;
    unsigned count;
};

#endif
```

My .c file:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void init_list(struct list my_list)
{
    my_list.header = NULL;
    my_list.count = 0;
}

void add_to_list(struct list * my_list, struct node * fruit_node)
{
    struct node * current;  /* node to traverse list */

    if(my_list -> header -> next == NULL) { /* check if no other nodes have been inserted, if so, insert at head */
        my_list -> header -> next = fruit_node;
    } else  {

        current = my_list -> header;    /* start at header */

        while(current->next != NULL) {  /* loop will terminate once end of list is encountered */
            current = current -> next;
        }

        current = fruit_node;           /* add node */

    }

}

int main()
{
    struct fruit fruit_array[5];
    struct list fruit_list;
    struct node * my_node;

    strcpy(fruit_array[0].name, "Apple");
    strcpy(fruit_array[1].name, "Mango");
    strcpy(fruit_array[2].name, "Banana");
    strcpy(fruit_array[3].name, "Pear");
    strcpy(fruit_array[4].name, "Orange");

    init_list(fruit_list);

    my_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    my_node -> data = &fruit_array[0];
    my_node -> next = NULL;

    add_to_list(&fruit_list, my_node);

    return 0;
}
```

For full disclosure, I tried posting this question earlier, where a user suggested that I needed to amend my code to pass by reference into my functions, rather than value, which I *think* I've done, but I'm still getting the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: use `gdb` and find out exactly where you are getting the segfault, that will help to find out why it's happening.

Comment: gdb says SIGSEGV received at line `while(current->next != NULL)`- I'm not sure why that loop is incorrect though

Comment: perhaps `current->next` never reaches `NULL`. While you are declaring fruit_list make sure it's properly initialized.

Comment: Ahh, wasn't passing by reference to my list initialization, thank you! Is there a way I can attribute the answer to this question to you?

Comment: @user3773076 You can write the answer yourself and site rakib as the source of the solution.

Comment: `my_list -> header -> next` Right off the bat you're dereferencing NULL at `my_list->header`.

Comment: "I needed to amend my code to pass by reference into my functions, rather than value, which I think I've done" -- You do? How odd, since the very first line of code is a function that takes a struct by value -- a better disclosure would be the fact that you didn't bother to read your code before posting it. (And actually, *every* parameter of *every* C function is passed by value, not reference. What you need to do is pass *references*, aka pointers, by value, rather than passing structs by value.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was passing by value to `init_list()`, which resulted in a *copy* of my list being initialized instead.

This subsequently caused the `while` loop in `add_to_list` to loop infinitely, as my uninitialized list was never set to null.

Solution was provided by [rakib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2231815/rakib).